# remote ssh not being allowed

Tags: linux, ssh

I had a 3rd party company harden our server.  I now need my server host to update our ssl certificate but they cannot ssh in to do so.  I will not even let them enter a username and password.

Now when the 3rd party was in there I had the same issue and they said they need to add my IP so I could get access.

So I am thinking I just need to add my server hosts ip to the iptable but this does not work.

Among other things I tried:

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s 10.10.10.10 -j ACCEPT
```

I can see it when I run

```
iptables -L
```

But this does not work

I also added the ip to hosts.allow to no avail

Comment: Try -I instead of -A

Comment: Is that an I(eye) or l (ell)

Comment: A I like "Instead"

Comment: Try -I instead of -A –  Iain  Seems to have worked. But why?  I see no difference in the iptable list.  That just seems odd to me.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the full contents of your INPUT chain all we can do is guess. Using `-A` adds a rule to the end of a chain. This usually causes the rule to be ignored because an existing rule acts upon the packets first and with iptables, order matters and first match wins.

Use `-I INPUT` to insert the rule into the beginning of the chain (or `-I INPUT n` for some meaningful value of `n` ) to insert it at a particular point in the chain so that it acted upon before anything else.

It is frequently the case that the last rule in the INPUT chain will be used to REJECT all packets that reach it.

Answer (score 0):

1. is sshd listening? log onto the console (if you can) and `telnet localhost 22`   do you get a response?
2. on a different host on the same subnet: `telnet [server ip] 22` do you get a response?

If you're not getting any tcp connection, then it's either iptables, tcpwrapper, or sshd configuration.

look at sshd_config for restrictions given by the ListenAddress, Match, or hostBasedAuthentication directives.

look at the logs for /var/log/secure and any tcp wrapper logs.

temporarily turn off (if you can) iptables with a `iptables --flush` and test the connection.

Comment: telnet localhost 22
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1).
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3
Connection closed by foreign host.

Comment: sshd_config  all are commented out so...no restrictions

Comment: the above Try -I instead of -A –  Iain   seems to have worked